# What is "skimmer like technology" as named in the rules for the Australian Remembrance Day Contest?

Tags: contest

In [the rules for the Australian Remembrance Day Contest](http://www.wia.org.au/members/contests/rdcontest/), I read:

> Use of skimmer like technology with a bandwidth greater than 3 KHz is not allowed.

What is considered for 'skimmer like technology' here? Are we talking about a CW decoding device or perhaps a panadapter (waterfall display of a range of frequencies)?

Answer (score 3):

I take it to mean any automated cw decoder with a receiving bandwidth of larger than 3khz is disallowed. Using one for small frequency ranges is fine, the problem is that users who can see a broad swath of spectrum and have automatic decoding over that whole spectrum have an unfair advantage over those using more traditional techniques, so this is meant to level the playing field a bit.